# Flash AS3 ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am following a tutorial on making a rhythm game in Flash, and am new to AS3. I keep getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property destroy on flash.display.Shape.
at source_fla::MainTimeline/removeButtons()[source_fla.MainTimeline::frame5:27]
at btnSongSelect/clickThis()[btnSongSelect::frame1:25]
```

referring to the following code:

```
//this function will remove all of the buttons from the stage
function removeButtons():void{
    //we're going to use the same loop
    for(var i:int=0;i<numChildren;i++){
        var remove = getChildAt(i);
        //set the target's destroy variable to true
        remove.destroy = true;
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain to me the cause of the error and a possible fix? Thank you.

Comment: It's same as [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878409/as3-error-referenceerror-error-1069-property-keycode-not-found-on-flash-disp).
Try to use `if (remove.hasOwnProperty("destroy"))` while iterating numChildren.

Comment: I tried doing the exact same thing as you suggested in my first question, but the problem is still persisting.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because [`getChildAt(i)`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildAt()) returns a [`DisplayObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) instance that doesn't have a `destroy` property.
A possible solution (based on the comment

> `//this function will remove all of the buttons from the stage`

) is to check `if(remove is ButtonClass)` which is expected.
Another option is as [Yasuyuki Uno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2567069/yasuyuki-uno) suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37879699/481281) is checking [`if(remove.hasOwnProperty('destroy'))`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#hasOwnProperty())

Comment: Or simply cast the value to that type.